# Postgres query won't populate a database table. Possible constraints interference?

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

I have a table named `pool_hashrate` with columns: `id` (PK), `hashrate`, `network_id` (FK), `pool_id` (FK). I would like to populate them with a query:

```
insert into pool_hashrate (
    hashrate, network_id, pool_id
)
select
    i+i::double precision, i, i
from generate_series(0, 15) AS i;
```

The tables were automatically generated via Hibernate. The SQL code snippet from pgAdmin:

```
CREATE TABLE public.pool_hashrate
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('pool_hashrate_id_seq'::regclass),
    hashrate double precision NOT NULL,
    network_id bigint NOT NULL,
    pool_id bigint NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pool_hashrate_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk52n7131wvbi6196idmf1wfb0e FOREIGN KEY (pool_id)
        REFERENCES public.pool_hashrate (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkjph0cotxu5udghsbbgtpysv66 FOREIGN KEY (network_id)
        REFERENCES public.network_hashrate (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.pool_hashrate
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Can constraints be the problem? When executing the query in pgAdmin I get the `rows affected -1` message.

---

**EDIT**

I keep getting the error `Null value in column “network_id” violates not-null constraint when adding new item.` Why is `null` being added there, if it's supposed to be `i`?

---

**EDIT 2**

In fact, before above query I am running 2 other queries to populate `network_hashrate` & `pool_hashrate`. Those queries are:

```
insert into network_hashrate (
    rep_date, hashrate
)
select
    current_timestamp - (s.a || ' hour')::interval,
    s.a::double precision
from generate_series(0, 15, 1) AS s(a);

insert into pool_def (
    name, date_from
)
select
    left(md5(random()::text), 10),
    current_timestamp - (s.a || ' hour')::interval
from generate_series(0, 15, 1) AS s(a);
```

So to answer your question, yes, I do have the records in `network_hashrate`. There should be no problem, I guess?

Comment: `network_id` references `public.network_hashrate (id)`, so do you have an `id` in `public.network_hashrate` for each `network_id` value you're inserting?

Comment: Check out my Edit2 please.

Comment: You're not explicitly setting the `id` value, so who knows what values are actually being used in the id. The values you're assuming exist are 0-15 - do ids exist for all those numbers in `network_hashrate`, including zero? Check your actual data in the table to confirm.

Comment: There's no `0` id. They start from 1-16.

Comment: So that's why. Your code is inserting the values of  `generate_series(0, 15)`. If you want to do 1-16, do `generate_series(1, 16)`

Comment: Sir, you're a genius. Thank you.